# Update dropdown in excel using date formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[Actual Worksheet in which I'm working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOvWI.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with adding a little VBA in the back ground this should do it for you.
You will need to change the following 3 variables to fit your needs startingRow, listColumn, ComparedDate.
See if this works!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim startingRow, endingRow, listColumn As Integer
    startingRow = 1 'Replace where you want to start updating, If you have a header start at 2
    listColumn = 2 'The Column your list is in
    For i = startingRow To Cells(Rows.Count, listColumn).End(xlUp).Row
        If Cells(i, listColumn).Value = "Pending" And Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, listColumn).Value) And (ComparedDate + 3 < Now()) Then
            Cells(i, listColumn).Value = "Overdue"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I dont know how should I put it in the vba I just want to put in the condition for overdue and if not overdue one can manually select from the available list of status

Comment: The VBA subroutine above will update the cell to "Overdue" if the cell is "Pending" and the date is greater than 3 days. Is that not what you are looking for?

Comment: No im trying to put in the formula such =IF(TODAY()+3>S6,tablerange,tablerange2) where tablerange = Overdue and tablerange 2 has list which contains pending,under validation, open like that

Comment: Okay, I see now. I think this link can explain how to set that up (Create Dependent Drop Down Lists) https://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html. If you create these dependent drop down lists, how will you change the "Overdue" cell to complete if you are doing dependent drop down lists? The other values will will never be available?

Comment: Yes thats where im stuck i dont know how to proceed

Comment: That why i think you should use that VBA subroutine (The subroutine will run every time you click on the sheet). Have one list with (Complete,Pending, Validation, Overdue). Set the list for all the cells you want, then let the VBA subroutine automatically set the Cell to Overdue if it needs it and then you can still have the other values still available in the drop down.

Comment: Yes I cant agree more but is there a way how to write a vba subroutine related to this part

Comment: 'Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
If Range("O5") < Date + 3 Then Range("Q5").Value = "Overdue"
Range("Q5").Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
Range("Q5").Interior.Color = vbRed
End Sub'
I have done this it works fine but not the issue is it works for only one cell how should I make work for all the cells I tried putting a range but it gives me an error

Comment: We absolutely can. Will you take a screenshot of the sheet and add it to question (I need to see what columns you are using) and I can help write the VBA subroutine for you?

Comment: Hi, Have added the image, a little background So as you can see in the image if the overdue status is yes I want macro to show overdue else user can select from the list in the image1 for e.g. OPEN,Pending etc etc

Comment: Upload a screen shot of your actual spreadsheet. If you want help writing the macro. I need to know what columns and rows you are using.